# How to add custom fonts globally

Tags: android, android-studio

How to change custom fonts in android studio? It seems like there is no easy way to do such a simple thing. I see that you can change the font of TextView but to change the font for a particular element, drawer or globally I can't seem to find an explenation.

Comment: There is nothing that says set this font to all textviews in my app, you have to set them individually

Answer (score 0):

Just Like @tycj said in the comments, unfortunately there is no way to set global fonts to the Textviews. But you can set custom type-styles and apply them as "textAppearance" to the TextViews.
For instance: Assume you have such a style in your project

```
 <style name="MyAPP.TextAppearance.Headline1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline1">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/your_font</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">48sp</item>
</style>
```

Then , you simply apply this to your theme.Like this :

```
 <item name="textAppearanceHeadline1">@style/MyAPP.TextAppearance.Headline1</item>
```

Now you can free to use this in a TextView but as the name of the style suggest, it is better to use this for the hearder TextViews in your app.

```
 <TextView
     ...
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline1" />
```

the good thing is that you can override these attributes

```
 <TextView
     ...
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline1"
    android:textSize="36sp" />
```

To get further information, you can check [here](https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#type-scale). Also I suggest checking [this sample project](https://material.io/design/material-studies/reply.html#type-scale) as well